# IP address instead of localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, signalr

I use SignalR for chat between two web applications (Both are on my local machine). SignalR hub is located in Application 1. This is what I use in Application 2:

`<script src="http://localhost:62192/signalr/hubs"></script>`

And it works fine. This is what I get for that request:

```
Remote Address:[::1]:62192
Request URL:http://localhost:62192/signalr/hubs
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

But when I type `<script src="http://192.168.9.200:62192/signalr/hubs"></script>` where `192.168.9.200` is my LAN address I got error:

```
Remote Address:192.168.9.200:62192
Request URL:http://192.168.9.200:62192/signalr/hubs
Request Method:GET
Status Code:503 Service Unavailable
```

What can be the problem?

EDIT: Also when I type `http://localhost:62192/signalr/hubs` in the browser I get the javascript file shown in browser. But with IP address instead of localhost I get `HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.` I actually get that error for any page in my applciation when trying to access it via ip address, its not only signalr problem...

Comment: Please show your configuration for the SignalR hubs. Usually its because you specify localhost (which is 127.0.0.1, not your IP), in order to specify to listen on all IP's, usually you can do a wildcard, ie http://*:62192/

Comment: The top (::1) is a IPv6 Address and the bottom one (192.168.9.200) is IPv4. I wonder if you are not listening on your endpoint to the right protocol...